# Spring context as Reader monad

Tags: spring, scala, dependency-injection, monads

I think that Spring bean `context` (which contains resolved and initialized java beans) looks like a `reader monad`. Does it make sense? Did anybody try to implement it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, see [Dependency Injection Without the Gymnastics](http://phillyemergingtech.com/2012/system/presentations/di-without-the-gymnastics.pdf)